# ¿Cómo actualizar correctamente el contenido de un iframe REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, iframe

estoy realizando un proyecto en React dentro del cual tengo un Context Provider el cual "almacena" cierta información que dependiendo del input de un usuario, irá cambiando. Dentro de esas propiedades va un template de html el cual necesito pasarselo a un iframe y poder actualizar el innerHtml. Tras llamar al provider desde el componente del iframe (por medio de useContext), si logro obtener con éxito el template del html, pero no logro indexarlo correctamente al iframe mediante la propiedad **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**. Alguien tiene idea de como poder solucionar esto? Cabe destacar que por cada vez que cambie la propiedad del template del html del provider, seguido debería actualizarse el innerhtml del iframe.

**Componente que incluye el iframe:**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { txtDataCT } from "../../context/txtAreaData/TxtDataCT";
export default function OutPutTxt(){
    const { htmlDataTemplate } = useContext(txtDataCT); //SI TRAE EL CONTENIDO CORRECTAMENTE
    //useEffect(() => {
      //  const node = document.querySelector('#outputTxt');
        //node.innerHTML = {htmlDataTemplate}
        //alert(node.innerHTML.value);
   // });    //INTENTÉ MEDIANTE UN USEEFFECT PERO NO FUNCIONA.
    return(
        <div className="outputBox border black-success border-5 m-1" id = "outDiv">
            <iframe id = 'outputTxt' dangerouslySetInnerHTML =  {{__html: htmlDataTemplate}} sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" > 
    
            </iframe>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Provider Context:**

```
import { Children, useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";


export const txtDataCT = createContext("fdsfsadfd");

export const TxtDataProvider = (props) =>{
    const [htmlDataTemplate, setHtmlData] = useState(`<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en"> 
        <head> 
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style type="text/css"></style>
        </head>
        <body><script></script></body>
    </html>`);
    /*
    */ 
    const [cssDataTemplate, setCssData] = useState(`<style type="text/css"></style>`);
    const [jsDataTemplate, setJsData] = useState(`<script></script>`);
    const [bdDataTemplate, setBdDataTemplate] = useState(`<body><script></script></body>`);
   
    const prueba = () => {
        console.log("Funciona funciona");
        return "exito";
    }
    return(
        <txtDataCT.Provider value = {{htmlDataTemplate, cssDataTemplate, jsDataTemplate, bdDataTemplate, setHtmlData, setCssData, setJsData, setBdDataTemplate}}>
            {props.children}
        </txtDataCT.Provider>
    )
}
```